# Sanitizing user input as part of an url

Tags: php, user-input, sanitization

I get a string, from an external clientside script, which must later be attached as part of an url. Now I am wondering what is the best way to santitize such data?

The string I get will have a structure like this:
`dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal`

This value will then be added to an url:
`http://the-page.com/dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal`

The url is then used as followed:

```
$link = htmlspecialchars("http://external-page.com/dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal", ENT_QUOTES);
$var = "<a href=\"javascript: window.open('$link')\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

Problem is, `htmlspecialchars` wont help to prevent execution of random javascript code, e.g. by adding this alert to the value:

```
dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal'+alert(\"breakout\")+'
```

Using `rawurlencode` wont help either, because it is not a value of a parameter but a real part of the url.
So what is the best way to sanitize the passed string when concatenating to the url?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Using `rawurlencode` only on the dynamic parts actually also didn't solve the issue, the javascript still got executed.
Test snippet:

```
$splitVal = "#staticVal:";
$tmpArr = explode($splitVal, "dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal'+alert(\"breakout\")+'");
$link = htmlspecialchars(sprintf("http://external-page.com/"."%s$splitVal%s", rawurlencode($tmpArr[0]), rawurlencode($tmpArr[1])), ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<a href=\"javascript: window.open('$link')\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

**Edit2:** 
Using `json_encode` when passing the string as javascript argument didn't help either. 
Adapted test snippet:

```
$splitVal = "#staticVal:";
$tmpArr = explode($splitVal, "dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal\"+alert('breakout')+\"");
$link = htmlspecialchars(sprintf("http://external-page.com/"."%s$splitVal%s", rawurlencode($tmpArr[0]), rawurlencode($tmpArr[1])), ENT_QUOTES);
echo  "<a href=\"javascript: window.open(".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($link), ENT_QUOTES).")\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

Adaptions done:
Switched the quotes in the malicous JS.
Moved `htmlspecialchars` around `json_encode`, because a double quoted string gets returned which would break the html otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completenes, I was able to solve that issue by simply putting `addslashes` on the dynamic part before using `rawurlencode`.
Both function calls are needed to prevent breaking out. Using `addslashes` prevents normal quotes (`'`,`"`) and `rawurlencode` prevents already encoded quotes (`%29`,`%22`) to cause harm.

So final solution looks like this:

```
$splitVal = "#staticVal:";
$tmpArr = explode($splitVal, "dynamicVal#staticVal:dynamicVal'+alert(\"breakout\")+'");
$link = htmlspecialchars(sprintf("http://external-page.com/"."%s$splitVal%s", rawurlencode(addslashes($tmpArr[0])), rawurlencode(addslashes($tmpArr[1]))), ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<a href=\"javascript: window.open('$link')\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`urlencode()`](http://de3.php.net/urlencode) for this. Not on the whole string but on the dynamic parts only.

```
$link = sprintf('http://external-page.com/%s#staticVal:%s', urlencode('dynamicVal'), urlencode('dynamicVal'));
$var  = "<a href=\"javascript: window.open('$link')\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

**EDIT**:

OK - I see your problem. I didn't realize that you insert the code into a JavaScript function call. You'll have to ensure that the JavaScript interpreter treats your link as a string argument to `window.open()`:

```
$link = sprintf('http://external-page.com/%s#staticVal:%s', urlencode('dynamicVal'), urlencode('dynamicVal'));
$var  = "<a href=\"javascript: window.open(".json_encode($link).")\">'Open URL'</a>";
```

Comment: I hoped to get around that to not first split the string, encode and concatenate again :) Some magic function I didn't know of yet :D Tough thanks, then I'll just do it that way.

Comment: Just tried to do it that way, the javascript still got executed. See Edit.

Comment: @Edit: That is sadly also not helping, I am still getting the JS to be executed. See second edit.